# Limit as $x$ approaches zero

Tags: limits

Would anyone know what $x\ln\left[\exp(a/x)+\exp(b/x)\right]$ would approach as $x$ approaches zero?  Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the signs of $a$ and $b$ and also the limit is taken from left or right

Comment: As mentioned, more info is needed. At this point it cannot be determined

Comment: A possible hint: I think it will be simpler if you use the variable change $u = \frac{1}{x}$ and consider the limit as $u \rightarrow \infty$ (actually, $|u| \rightarrow \infty,$ unless $x$ is approaching $0$ on the right).

Comment: Oh, I did not know more info was needed! x is non-negative, so approaches zero from the right.  I don't know the signs of a or b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let without loss of generality $a \geqslant b$. Then

$$\ln \left( \exp \frac{a}{x} + \exp \frac{b}{x}\right) = \ln \exp \frac{a}{x} + \ln \left(1 + \exp \frac{b-a}{x}\right) = \frac{a}{x} + \ln \left(1 + \exp \frac{b-a}{x}\right).$$

Since $b-a \leqslant 0$, the argument of the logarithm is bounded (either constant or converging to $0$), and hence

$$\lim_{x\searrow 0} x\cdot\ln \left( \exp \frac{a}{x} + \exp \frac{b}{x}\right) = \max \{a,b\}.$$

The method and result generalise to an arbitrary finite number of terms,

$$\lim_{x\searrow 0} x\cdot \ln \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \exp \frac{a_k}{x}\right) = \max \{ a_k : 1\leqslant k \leqslant m\}.$$

Comment: I am so grateful to all of you!!! This site is full of the nicest people on the web!!